# How to set up path for gems with the Fish shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How do I properly set up path for gems with the Fish shell?

> sanoy@nice-system ~/D/c/h/bellevue> gem install bundle
>
> WARNING:  You don't have /home/sanoy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin in your PATH,
>             gem executables will not run. Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1 
>   Parsing documentation for bundle-0.0.1 Done installing
>
> documentation for bundle after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
>
> sanoy@nice-system ~/D/c/h/bellevue> bundle install fish:
>   Unknown command 'bundle'

**config.fish file**

```
set PATH </home/sanoy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin> $PATH

set -gx PATH $PATH </home/sanoy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin>
```

Comment: Try leaving single line in your fish.config: `set -gx PATH /home/sanoy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin $PATH`

Comment: Good job! Reposted the advice as an answer, you might accept it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered in comments, leaving single line in `fish.config` fixes the problem:

```
set -gx PATH ~/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin $PATH
```

Answer (score 9):

It is likely better to use a dynamically updated path based on version, especially if version updates without distro updates like in Arch Linux

```
set -U fish_user_paths (ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin $fish_user_paths
```