# RVM is not setting my PATH in `fish`, but should be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, fish

I have been using RVM for a year and a half now.

Had the RVM PATH warning surface from every command invocation, but otherwise RVM was still functioning appropriately.  I may have fixed that warning with instructions from this link: [StackOverflow - Getting “Warning! PATH is not properly set up” when doing rvm use 2.0.0 --default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul)
This involved putting `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into one of my `bash`-related shell configuration profiles.

Adding that one, or too many of those in the other available files in the call chain, may have lead to this weird (mostly?) aesthetic error: [SuperUser - Why am I having / how can I fix this error: “shell_session_update: command not found”](https://superuser.com/questions/1044130/why-am-i-having-how-can-i-fix-this-error-shell-session-update-command-not-f)

Started getting the RVM PATH error again.  I did not think this at the time, but looking back at the problem, I wonder if I had just updated my `fish` shell from around 2.2.0 to 2.5.0, which may be causing my further **actual** PATH errors (not warnings) as well...

Executing `rvm reset` did not help.

Executing `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` seemed to help a current terminal, but not others, even on restart.  Decided to reinstall.

Ran `rvm implode`.  Removed or commented out all of the RVM lines in all of my shell configuration files.

Ran through [RVM - Integration - Fish Shell](https://rvm.io/integration/fish), which is also covered here for [StackOVerflow - Can't get RVM to switch rubies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082425/cant-get-rvm-to-switch-rubies), which involves doing some of [RVM - Installing RVM - Quick (guided) Install](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) first.

- Used this combination: `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --with-default-gems="rails haml" --with-gems="hirb"`.
- Downloaded the `rvm` `fish` function.
- Added `rvm default` config to `config.fish`.

### Problem

My `ruby` executable is the wrong version:

```
⋊> ~ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

It is the system ruby, and not the RVM-set version:

```
⋊> ~ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I have no bundle command:

```
⋊> ~ which bundle
⋊> ~ bundle
fish: Unknown command 'bundle'
⋊> ~ functions bundle
```

Thus I cannot use Rails without bundle helping me to install the gem:

```
⋊> ~ rails
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

My `PATH` and `GEM_PATH` variables do not seem to update, as can be seen below.

My question would be to ask how to get those variables to update?  Something similar to this link: [StackOverflow - RVM doesn't set correct gem path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840366/rvm-doesnt-set-correct-gem-path)

### More background

```
⋊> ~ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
⋊> ~ functions rails
⋊> ~ ⨯
⋊> ~ head /usr/bin/rails
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Stub rails command to load rails from Gems or print an error if not installed.
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"
if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end
```

```
⋊> ~ which rvm
⋊> ~ ⨯

⋊> ~ ls ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish
/Users/username/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish

⋊> ~ functions rvm|head
function rvm --description 'Ruby enVironment Manager'
  # run RVM and capture the resulting environment
  set --local env_file (mktemp -t rvm.fish.XXXXXXXXXX);
  # echo "DEBUG: env_file: $env_file"
  # This finds where RVM's root directory is and sources scripts/rvm from within it.  Then loads RVM in a clean environment and dumps the environment variables it generates out for us to use.
  bash -c 'PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH;RVMA=$(which rvm);RVMB=$(whereis rvm | sed "s/rvm://");source $(if test $RVMA;then echo $RVMA | sed "s/\/bin\//\/scripts\//";elif test $RVMB; then echo $RVMB | sed "s/rvm/rvm\/scripts\/rvm/"; else echo ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; fi); rvm "$@"; status=$?; env > "$0"; exit $status' $env_file $argv

  # apply rvm_* and *PATH variables from the captured environment
  and eval (grep -E '^rvm|^GEM_PATH|^GEM_HOME' $env_file | grep -v '_clr=' | sed '/^[^=]*PATH/s/:/" "/g; s/^/set -xg /; s/=/ "/; s/$/" ;/; s/(//; s/)//')
  # needed under fish >= 2.2.0
```

```
⋊> ~ bash -c 'which rvm'
⋊> ~ bash -c 'whereis rvm'
⋊> ~ bash -c 'echo ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm;'
/Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm
⋊> ~ head /Users/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# rvm : Ruby enVironment Manager
# https://rvm.io
# https://github.com/rvm/rvm

# partial duplication marker dkjnkjvnckbjncvbkjnvkj
# prevent from loading in sh shells
if
  builtin test -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" -o -n "${KSH_VERSION:-}"
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm use
Using /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5 with gemset ux-rails3.2
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

```
⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/
default@  ruby-2.1.5/
⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/
bin/  config  include/  lib/  share/
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm env
export PATH="/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2'
export GEM_PATH='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5'
export IRBRC='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.1.5'
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm env --path
/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2
⋊> ~ cat /Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2
export PATH="/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2'
export GEM_PATH='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5'
export IRBRC='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.1.5'
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm 2.1.5 do rvm env --path
/Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.5
⋊> ~ cat /Users/username/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.5
export PATH="/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5'
export GEM_PATH='/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5'
export IRBRC='/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.1.5'
```

```
⋊> ~ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

```
⋊> ~ gem list
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.7.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
hirb (0.7.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.5 (found in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5)
   (default)
   global
=> ux-rails3.2
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm gemset dir
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2
```

```
⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/
bin
cache
environment
wrappers

⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2/bin/
⋊> ~

⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin/
bundle
bundler
executable-hooks-uninstaller
ruby_executable_hooks

⋊> ~ ls /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/
haml
ruby_executable_hooks
tilt
```

```
⋊> ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/mysql/bin /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin /usr/local/opt/findutils/bin /Users/username/bin /usr/local/mysql/bin /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin /usr/local/opt/findutils/bin /Users/username/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/munki /opt/puppetlabs/bin /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS

⋊> ~ echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ux-rails3.2:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
```

```
⋊> ~ cat .ruby-gemset .ruby-version
ux-rails3.2
ruby-2.1.5
```

```
⋊> ~ grep "rvm" .config/fish/config.fish  .bashrc .bash_profile .profile .zshrc .mkshrc .zlogin /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
.config/fish/config.fish:# Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul
.config/fish/config.fish:rvm default;
.bashrc:# From running the command 'rvm get head ...'.  Needs to be at the bottom, so no other PATH entries can change the order.
.bashrc:# Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul
.bashrc:# export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
.bash_profile:# [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
.profile:# export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
.profile:# [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
grep: .zshrc: No such file or directory
grep: .mkshrc: No such file or directory
grep: .zlogin: No such file or directory

⋊> ~ ls .gemrc
ls: cannot access '.gemrc': No such file or directory
```

```
⋊> ~ rvm -v; ruby -v; rails -v; echo "gem version "(gem -v); rake -V; bundle -v;
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
gem version 2.0.14.1
rake, version 0.9.6
fish: Unknown command 'bundle'
```

Mac 10.12.3

iTerm2 3.0.15

fish, version 2.5.0

### Other stuff

- More related to `bash`, but may still apply since the `fish` `rvm` function uses bash inside: [StackOVerflow - Need to Fix PATH in my bashrc File for RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285083/need-to-fix-path-in-my-bashrc-file-for-rvm)
- Simplistic approach, but I need the RVM dynamic feature working: [StackOverflow - How to set up path for gems with the Fish shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801840/how-to-set-up-path-for-gems-with-the-fish-shell)

Comment: The `rvm` command has problems. See, for example, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4039. I also can't make sense of your issue. You say you're using `rvm` with fish but your first paragraph talks about bash and shows code that isn't compatible with fish.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I use rbenv without issue in fish

Comment: I was providing some context, but also the `rvm.fish` function calls `bash` underneath, saving off its environment, and then 'somewhat' applying it to the fish's environment, so I wanted to include that information, and any other information as much as possible,  in case they affected this Q&A's efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some kind of solution

So far I have it barely working by making the change from:

`grep -E '^rvm|^GEM_PATH|^GEM_HOME'`

to:

`grep -E '^rvm|^[^=]*PATH|^GEM_HOME'`

Not sure what side effects that will cause, but from looking at the `rvm.fish` code, that would seem to be missing.

### Related aside

An older version had the `^[^=]*PATH\` term in it, like my system's previous version, and can also be randomly found here: [GitHub Gist - ToniRib/rvm.fish](https://gist.github.com/ToniRib/a5b92fe4f104664ab0baab6d2af0e869)
That is for escaping the pipe (|) characters, but I can't see why that is needed inside of single quotes.  My fix works specifically without the backslashes, and just plain pipe characters.

### Non-functional alternative

I have alternatively tried a patch without the other code such as this one:

```
and set -xg GEM_PATH (echo $GEM_PATH | sed 's/ /:/g')
and set -xg PATH (echo $GEM_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g') $MY_RUBY_HOME/bin $PATH
```

I am continuing to add lines to it, but still see various errors.  First I needed the "rubies" directory for the correct version of `ruby`, then both gem paths modified with spaces for `fish`, and still I am having issues, so taking `bash`'s `PATH` environment variable wholesale and letting the `rvm` script do its own work is the best I have so far.